# How to change the coordinates of Shapefiles from another GIS platform to QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have over 800 shapefiles which when paired with google maps/bing maps, the point is off by at least 1000 km. Been scratching my head to make this work by changing the default CRS. (Previously was in Atlantic Ocean)

Is it possible to change the longitude and latitude manually for all 800 shapefiles? (its a long-winded process) or is there any other method I could employ for this?

Currently using CRS Layer : GDM2000 / Johor Grid

[image: The pic shows how far the points are off]

Comment: It looks like your data is in the wrong spatial reference... what's the right one? If it came up in the Atlantic Ocean it may be based on a local datum like http://georepository.com/datum_6238/Indonesian-Datum-1974.html which may not be correctly interpreted by QGIS.

Comment: The orignal data was in fact WGS 84. I tried my luck by selecting CRS from the country of origin for the shapefiles and thats the closest I can get to the correct point. Is there any way to make QGIS interpret it correctly?

Comment: If they're not lining up I would suggest quite strongly that they have been mis-defined and are not truly WGS84. Google uses Web Mercator which should line up with WGS84/Geographic quite well in QGIS.

Comment: Do your shapefiles  include a `.prj`? If so, please edit in the contents of one these.

Comment: If the shapefile has no .prj, QGIS assigns WGS84 as default projection unless you choose the right one. It would help if you give sample coordinate pairs of several known points, and the lat/lon where you would expect them. Please edit your question to include them.

Comment: Does the original WGS84 coordinates shown at the right position? If yes, then you have to check the projection. Otherwise the original layer is not in WGS84.

Comment: @Richard Law - It does not contain any .prj files unfortunately

Comment: @AndreJ --- The sample coordinates are:
Original location with default WGS84 - 547084 , 262923
Location it should be: 11470498 , 250240

Comment: @Zoltan - It does not. The thing is when I used CRS of GDM2000/Johor Grid, all the points gets closer to the location but still off by 1000km

Comment: Can you give the target in lonlat degrees as well? Maybe taken from Google Map/Earth?

Comment: You have to investigate to find the projection of the original data. Try `orginfo -al your_shapefile` to see the coordinates in your file. Are these lat, lon in Malaysia?

Comment: @AndreJ - I am still very new to this, read quite a few pages on how to convert those coords to lonlat but no luck so far unfortunately. I can't seem to identify the original CRS of the shapefiles.

Comment: @Zoltan - You're right, it's in Malaysia! Could you elaborate more on where do I put these codes "orginfo -al your_shapefile" on? My only clue is the python console in QGIS.

Comment: It should be `ogrinfo`, but without a .prj file you are out of luck with that.

Comment: orginfo is part of the gdal utilities, these are usually installed with QGIS on Windows, you can use them from a command window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `EPSG:3375 GDM2000 / Peninsula RSO`:

[image]

If you encounter offsets of about 25m, use `EPSG:3168 Kertau (RSO) / RSO Malaya (m)` instead:

[image]

Once you have saved a shapefile with the right CRS, you can copy the .prj file to the names of the others.

The Johor Grid you have taken might be highly accurate for local surveying, but not suitable for data of the whole peninsular. To avoid misinterpretation, both CRS are intentionally offset by 1000km.

Answer (score 0):

The points are still slightly off but I've managed to google a plugin called Vector-Bender Master for QGIS that could correct this.

Following the input given by @AndreJ, this is the results:
[image: This is the product following @AndreJ advice]

Comment: Have you tried both CRS? At least one should fit.

Comment: @AndreJ - I did use both. 'EPSG:3168 Kertau (RSO) / RSO Malaya (m)' brings it slightly closer by fixing the upwards position. The points have to move to the left side in order to be fully aligned with the base map. Any thoughts on this, AndreJ? I'm still in the midst of trial & error and googling session.

Comment: There are some problems with the omerc projection used, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54758/coordinate-system-malaysia-rso-projection-not-lining-up-in-qgis-and-arcgis-for. The workaround is to play with the parameters using a custom CRS. Or find some arcgis user to reproject the data to UTM.